# Is it possible to have two or more GLSurfaceView in the same layout?

Tags: android, layout, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

Is it possible to have two or more GLSurfaceView in the same activity (and layout) ?

I've tried it and I just one of them doubled... how can I do it right?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991095/how-can-i-use-multiple-glsurfaceview-components-in-the-same-layout