# Two GlSurfaceViews don't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In my game , I want  to create **"live background"** using `GlSurfaceView` as a background which is placed inside the main activity. 
In addition, there is a fragment in the activity layout. Another `GlSurfaceView` is inside that fragment.

The two  `GlSurfaceViews`  don't work together, I can only see the **"live background"**.
Some one help please:)?
(I am using OpenGLES 2.0 )

Comment: I believe you cannot have two SurfaceView components in the same hierarchy until recent versions of Android

Comment: So the only way to solve this problem is by merging the two GlSurfaceViews ?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22746240).